# Swift Formatting Localized Strings

Tags: string, swift, string-formatting, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

We are using OneSky for the translating of strings. We use positional specifiers within the string files. The problem that I'm running into is when using %s in the string.

I have a string: `"dist_unit_mask" = "%1$s %2$s";` which I read from the `Localization.strings` file and attempt to format: `String(format: NSLocalizedString(@"dist_unit_mask", comment: @"Distance and Units"), dist, unit)`

This causes the application to crash, but when I change the string to `"dist_unit_mask" = "%1$@ %2$@";`, the app does not crash. What could be causing the app to crash when using `$s` instead of `%@`? I would like to not modify the strings files after downloaded from OneSky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%s` format (with or without positional specifiers) expects a
*C string*, i.e. a pointer to a NUL-terminated sequences of `char`,
and not a Swift string.

If you really have to keep the `%s` format then

```
String(format: NSLocalizedString(...),
    (dist as NSString).cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    (unit as NSString).cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

should work.